# How do you pass arguments to Blaze components programmatically?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze

The meteor-react [tutorial](http://tutorial-viewer.meteor.com/tutorial/8/react) instructs you to create your Meteor login buttons by calling Blaze.render:

```
this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
  React.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
```

The account-ui package documentation says that if you want to align the login dropdown on the right edge of the screen, you should use

```
{{> loginButtons align="right"}}'
```

Unfortunately,the documentation of the `Blaze.render()` function doesn't indicate any parameters that my JavaScript can use to pass the equivalent of `align="right"`.

How can I tell Blaze to render the template with `align="right"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using [`Blaze.renderWithData`](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_renderwithdata) ?

```
this.view = Blaze.renderWithData(Template.loginButtons, {
  align: "right"
}, React.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
```

Comment: Huh. I saw `Blaze.renderWithData()`, but the description of that argument ("The data context to use") did not sound like it was talking about what I needed. Thanks!